# How to add a module in Swift app via cocoa pod?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am trying to add a module (SwiftyJSON) in my app but getting error. I followed https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift tutorial for installing cocoapod on my Mac OS and it got installed successfully. I also got the module installed successfully. However, when I am trying to load the module in my swift file using the `import SwiftyJSON` statement I am getting error that says `No such module SwiftyJSON`.

Documentation for SwiftyJSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApplePaySwag' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ApplePaySwag
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'AEXML'

  target 'ApplePaySwagTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) try putting use_frameworks! outside of target (under platform)
2) pod install
3) if import doesn't work try cleaning application (cmd + shift + k)
4) also clean derived data from the project -> xcode -> window -> projects -> derived data (delete)

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestingModules' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestingModules
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'AEXML'

  target 'TestingModulesTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestingModulesUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Still no luck :(  Followed all your instructions.

Comment: i edited my answed with podfile which i created and in which SwiftyJSON import works ... like i said after writign podfile just use pod install and everything should work. you must open project.xcworkspace file and not .xcodeproj

Comment: Perfect :) That worked. Yes, you were correct. I missed opening the workspace file earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your podfile

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    use_frameworks!
    def common_pods   
    end
    target 'ApplePaySwag' do
        common_pods
        pod 'SwiftyJSON'
        pod 'AEXML'
    end
    target 'ApplePaySwagTests' do
        common_pods
    end
```

and Run pod install,

then clean your project..

after that close the ApplePaySwag.xcodeproj and open ApplePaySwag.xcworkspace